# Android Calculator using textview

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to build a calculator app. i use textview to recieve the value from button, whenever user click on button. but when user click on the button second time then the value in textview is overwritten by the value of the previous button.
But i want to get the whole value in textview.
Ex: Suppose user click on the 1 then 2,then 3 so number appear in textview will be 123.
So please guide me.

Comment: if(clickedButton == buttonNumber1){ textview.setText(textview.getText()+"1");}

Answer (score 5):

> when user click on the button second time then the value in textview is overwritten by the value of the previous button

Use [`append()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead of `setText()` to add on to the existing string in your TextView.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to add the number to the string in your textview, instead of replacing it. Put the following in you `onClick` method for each button

```
String s = textview.getText().toString();
textview.setText(s + "1")
```

Comment: Did you mean `textview.setText(s + "1")`? There is no `TextView#edittext()` method. :)